# How to append data to excel into single excel sheet using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I am trying to read log files from different folders and store then in an Excel sheet.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import bs4

path = "D:\\logfolder"
filelist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("History.txt"):
            filelist.append(os.path.join(root, file))

for name in filelist:             
        print(name + "\n")   # D:\logfolder\logfolder_1\History.txt
                             # D:\logfolder\logfolder_2\History.txt
                             # D:\logfolder\logfolder_3\History.txt
                             # D:\logfolder\logfolder_4\History.txt

for name in filelist:
    with open(name,"r") as f:
        soupObj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")

    df = pd.DataFrame([(x["uri"], *x["t"].split("T"), x["u"], x["desc"])
                       for x in soupObj.find_all("log")],
                      columns=["Database", "Date", "Time", "User", "Description"])
    df.to_excel("logfile.xlsx", index=False)
```

The expected output is to get a final Excel sheet of all `logfile.txt` from all log-folders but I am only getting the data from the last `logfile.txt` with its **logfolder_4** in the final Excel sheet with its **logfile.xlsx**.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Replace the last *for-loop bloc* by this :

```
dfList = []
for name in filelist:
    with open(name,"r") as f:
        soupObj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")

    df = pd.DataFrame([(x["uri"], *x["t"].split("T"), x["u"], x["desc"])
                       for x in soupObj.find_all("log")],
                      columns=["Database", "Date", "Time", "User", "Description"])
    
    dfList.append(df)

pd.concat(dfList).to_excel("logfile.xlsx", index=False)
```